# gfortran include files ignored even with -I options

Tags: compilation, fortran, gfortran

I am trying to compile using gfortran using the following:

```
$ gfortran -I/usr/local/include -O3 -Wall -Wno-uninitialized -fbounds-check -g alignparts_lmbfgs.f90 /home/vincent/test/lmbfgs/Lbfgsb.3.0/lbfgsb.f /home/vincent/test/lmbfgs/Lbfgsb.3.0/linpack.f /home/vincent/test/lmbfgs/Lbfgsb.3.0/blas.f /home/vincent/test/lmbfgs/Lbfgsb.3.0/timer.f /home/vincent/test/lmbfgs/minimal_libraries/imlib2010.a /home/vincent/test/lmbfgs/minimal_libraries/genlib.a -o alignparts_lmbfgs.exe -lfftw3 -lm
```

but it gave me the error

```
alignparts_lmbfgs.f90:105: Error: Can't open included file '/usr/include/fftw3.f'
```

even though I specified the -I opitions where the fftw3.f resides.

What am I doing wrong? I don't have root privileges so I can't just move the files from /usr/local/include to /usr/inlcude

I am a noob in compiling. I am only compiling because this is the only way I am getting the executable. Please be as noob-proof as possible when explaining. Thank you so much!

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran related questions.

Comment: Do not add any SOLVED to the question title. Accept the answer by clicking on the tisck left of it if it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler reports:

```
alignparts_lmbfgs.f90:105: Error: Can't open included file '/usr/include/fftw3.f'
```

This means that your source file `alignparts_lmbfgs.f90` contains
a line #105 like:

```
INCLUDE '/usr/include/fftw3.f'
```

which tells the compiler to copy the file `/usr/include/fftw3.f` in place
of that line #105. But there is no such file.

You have passed the compiler option `-I/usr/local/include` which
tells the compiler to search for included files in `/usr/local/include`,
and you say:

> I specified the -I options where the fftw3.f resides.

So probably there *is* such a file as `/usr/local/include/fftw3.f`?

In that case, can change:

```
INCLUDE '/usr/include/fftw3.f'
```

to:

```
INCLUDE '/usr/local/include/fftw3.f'
```

However, if you do that, then the compiler option:

```
-I/usr/local/include
```

is pointless, because `/usr/local/include/fftw3.f` is an absolute filename:
it either exists or it doesn't.

If you want the program to be compilable independently of the absolute location
of `fftw3.f` - which is emphatically the best practice - then replace line #105 with:

```
INCLUDE 'fftw3.f'
```

Then, if `fftw3.f` is in fact located in `/usr/local/include`, you can compile
the program with the option `-I/usr/local/include`, and in general if the file
is located in directory `/look/here/for/headers`, you can compile the program
with the option `-I/look/here/for/headers`.

Comment: Thanks! There's indeed an include line in line 105! I have changed that line into the directory containing fftw3.f! And it compiles successfully! Thanks for the help and your explanation is very clear and detailed